# GIF loader is loading very slowly in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, animated-gif

Actually we have animated loader in the GIF image.

We are loading that GIF image as background image of ionic application to remove the white screen which is coming for the window.open('URL','_self').

We have placed that GIF image in the the div tag in the body index.html and and style for that class in the index page.

Please check the below code:

HTML:

```
<body class="loader">
 <div ng-app="inscribe" class="platform-ios platform-cordova platform-webview">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
   .loader {
   background-image: url("img/splash_loader.gif");
   background-position: center center;
   background-size:100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 100vh;
   }
  </style>
```

Please provide your suggestion as soon as possible. Your suggestions are welcomed.